# how to build test case for testing with fetch call in reactJs using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following code

```
getFullName() {

    var urlendPoint = new URL(propertiesInFile.urltoPing)

    var params = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName
    }

    urlendPoint.search = new URLSearchParams(params)

    fetch(urlendPoint).then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
        ...perform some actions...
      }
    })
      .catch(error => {
        alert("Please check the names and try again");
      });
  }
```

The propertiesInFile are just hard coded values that I have defined in another js file.

In the above code, I can't seem to mock the fetch call. How do I test this function in react such that I can get the states (of firstname and lastName) in the function, cover the catch block and also try the fetch call that is in place.

Answer (score 0):

In your test you can assign fetch to a mock function something like this

```
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);
```

You can find more details on this [website](https://medium.com/@rishabhsrao/mocking-and-testing-fetch-with-jest-c4d670e2e167)